# How to recycle a webview on jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-jetpack-compose

I have an app that emulates `ViewPager` behavior via `HorizontalPager`. Each Pager has a `WebView`, and the `ViewPager` will release `WebView` for pages that are far from the current page. What should I do in Jetpack Compose? It seems the composable should not be destroyed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. `ViewPager` is a lazy view and it's not gonna store non visible views.

In clear Compose all you need to cache is scrolling position and some other state variables, and Compose will do that.

But when you're using `AndroidView`, you had to manage it by yourself. I'm not sure if it's possible to retrieve `WebView` scrolling position, but even if you can - the page still will be re-loaded.

A possible solution is storing `WebViews` in a state like this:

```
val webViews = remember(LocalContext.current) { mutableStateMapOf<Int, WebView>() }
val state = rememberPagerState()
LaunchedEffect(state.currentPage) {
    webViews.keys.forEach { key ->
        val maxCacheDistance = 3
        if (abs(key - state.currentPage) >= maxCacheDistance) {
            webViews.remove(key)
            println("webView $key deinited")
        }
    }
}
HorizontalPager(
    count = 10,
    state = state,
) { page ->
    val url = "https://duckduckgo.com/?q=$page"
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context -> 
            webViews[page] ?: run {
                WebView(context).also { webView ->
                    webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
                    webViews[page] = webView
                }
            }
        },
        update = { webView ->
            if (webView.url != url) {
                webView.loadUrl(url)
            }
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
}
```

Comment: I think the WebView should be recycled if the Composable of the WebView is not called, so maybe I can add a condition for determining if invoke the composable

Comment: @Kennir what do you mean by "WebView is not called"? I only create it when it firstly appears

Comment: Hi @philip-dukhov,  I mean do not invoke composable function which contains WebView If current index is far enough away, for examples: if (abs(pageIndex, currentIndex) < 3) { ComposableWebView() }

Comment: @Kennir `HorizontalPager` works lazy, it won't call content for all of your pages. At initial load it only will load first and second items.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not explain it clearly, for example, I want to destroy the webview on the first page to free up memory if the current page is moved to 3 or large, then recreate the webview if the current page is moved back to 2 or small

Comment: @Kennir Now I've go it. I've added an example of how you can track it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a function to the class that implements the WebView that calls onDestroy and replaces the current page with a blank page. Replacing the current web page with a blank page will terminate any javascript. For example, in my app I use a WebView to play YouTube videos:

```kotlin
class VideoPlayerView() : WebView(ctx) {
    fun terminateWebView() {
        // Reload the webview with a blank page. This is needed to kill any video playing.
        loadData("<html><body></body></html>", "text/html", "base64")
        this.destroy()
    }
}
```

You should call your termination function when the you navigate back to the previous screen. Whether you want to clear the webview when you swipe tabs is a decision you have to make. In my app, because I play videos in one tab, I need to terminate the video when the user swipes to another tab. But if your app is not playing media content like videos, then you probably don't need to terminate the webview.